# HP 4120 phone and Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip, pbx

I got a task to set up a cheap PBX for HP 4120 phones. I want to try Asterisk, but I can't find any info on connecting HP 4120 to any SIP PBX.

So here's the question: are HP 4120 compatible with Asterisk? If yes, is there any info on setting up these phones with Asterisk?

Comment: looks like it is a Lync only handset https://www.lyncstore.co.uk/_assets/downloads/hp%204120%20ip/hp%204120%20ip%20phone%20datasheet.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For downvoters: there's really NO info on connecting HP 4120 to SIP PBX on the Internet. Many references to Lync though. I just couldn't let a thought that such a pricey phone doesn't support anything except Lync. HP support is redirecting to local dealers and dealers are redirecting back to HP support.

Anyway, I found someone who broke this circle several years ago and the answer is: NO, HP 4120 supports only Lync.

Thanks everyone and sorry if I wrote something wrong.